# setMaxResult not working in MSSQL server 2014 with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select distinct(id) From Table where plant=?1").setParameter(1, plant);
        query.setFirstResult((pageNo-1) * pageSize); 
        query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
        List<String> Ids = query.getResultList();
```

This code is working fine with SQL Server 2008 but when I migrated database from 2008 to 2014 this gives me following error:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.throwNotScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:376)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetIsScrollable(SQLServerResultSet.java:399)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.absolute(SQLServerResultSet.java:1474)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.absolute(WrappedResultSet.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractResultSetProxyHandler.java:104)
    ... 170 more
```

I have tried following:
1. Changed jdbc driver from `sqljdbc4.0.jar` to `sqljdbc4.2.jar`.

2. `LIMIT` not supported in sql server

String query = "select distinct ID from Table limit "
                     + offset + ", " + noOfRecords;

3. `ROW_NUMBER()` not a good solution because I want distinct records

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate calls methods on a forward only results set that are only available and supported (by specification!) on scrollable result sets. You need to file a bug with Hibernate that they should explicitly ask for a scrollable result set if they are going to call those methods. Note that SQL Server might not know `LIMIT`, but it does have `TOP`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx

Comment: @rohit-k Did you resolve this problem finally? How?

Comment: @Krzysiek not able to resolve...I have asked client side developer to handle paging at there end :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [Wrong hibernate dialect for MSSQL 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521144/wrong-hibernate-dialect-for-mssql-2014?answertab=active#tab-top). I think that could be related to a wrong dialect resolved for Hibernate for SQL Server 2014

Comment: I agree. I had this exact problem and configuring SQLServer2012Dialect fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423126/1255493

This solved my problem.