# What is the Hibernate dialect for Microsoft SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate

I have searched online but could not find the Hibernate dialect to use for Microsoft SQL Server 2014. Which dialect should be used?

Comment: Look in to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521144/wrong-hibernate-dialect-for-mssql-2014

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The latest dialect for Microsoft SQL Server is [SQLServer2012Dialect](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServer2012Dialect.html), which is the one you should use for now. See [this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) for all supported dialects.

Actually, [there was a bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9570) where Hibernate defaulted to the SQL Server 2000 dialect when SQL Server 2014 was used. This bug [has been resolved](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/1353) (in versions *5.2.0* and *5.1.1*) and the solution was:

> Added version 12 to the switch statement so that SQLServer2012Dialect is now returned by default, as SQL Server 2014 is much more similar to SQL Server 2012 than SQL Server 2000

In time, a SQLServer2014Dialect will probably appear, which of course mean you would switch to that dialect then.